# Android - Can not fill the content in bottom

Tags: android, xml

I want to create bottom bar in android. 
I have try like this.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/WHITE_BACKGROUND"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/feedCampaignImageButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"            
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/customer_detail_search_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_search_ldpi"
                android:contentDescription="@string/none" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/customer_detail_home_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_home_ldpi"
                android:contentDescription="@string/none" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/customer_detail_logout_button"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/logout"
                android:contentDescription="@string/none" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logout_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Logout"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

The output is like this:-
[image: Output Image]

Expected output:-
[image]

I can not fill the bottom with this three images. If I give width for the Linear Layout it showing exact result. But in mobile, if I flip the mobile mean the alignment is not good. 
Please let me know how to fill the bottom bar with three images.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: How do you want to "fill" the bottom bar? You want to scale the images or increase the distance between images? You want to center them? What is your idea?

Comment: post an demo screen shot to show the expected output.

Comment: You can use footer also put three image in separate footer.xml file and include in main.xml

Comment: @KeTaN.. Thanks for your hint.. Helps me lots.

Answer (score 0):

You have this :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

the: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` of the linear layout will make it have the width value `45dp` of the imagebutton.

I would suggest that you give ids to the three linear layouts and in the onCreate after getting the values of the linear layouts in the code file, using display metrics get the width of the screen and set the minimum width of the linear layouts to the width of the screen / 3. like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager.getDisplayMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;

mLnrOne.setMinimumWidth(width/3); ---> do this for the other two linear layouts as well.
```

Hope that helps!